# How to apply a function a function on a column without "apply"?

Tags: pandas

I have a dataframe like:

```
A    | B   | C   | ...
1000 | 600 | 600 | productdesc
1500 | 400 | 600 | productdesc
1000 | 600 | 300 | productdesc
```

I want to create a new column D based on:

```
def get_result():
    if A > 1000 or B > 600 or C > 600:
        return 1
    else:
        return 0
```

Resulting in:

```
A    | B   | C   | ...         | D
1000 | 600 | 600 | productdesc | 0
1500 | 400 | 600 | productdesc | 1
1000 | 600 | 300 | productdesc | 0
```

Due to the dataframe size I can't use .apply because it's slow.

But I don't find a fast way to apply a function onto a column / create a new column based on a function with arguments based on other columns?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let us try `any`

```
df['D'] = df.gt({'A':1000,'B':600,'C':600}).any(1).astype(int)
#df['D']
Out[327]: 
0    0
1    1
2    0
dtype: int32
```

Comment: That gives me "ValueError: Unable to coerce to Series, length must be 10: given 3". My dataframe has 10 columns, some int, some object, some string. Only A B C are relevant for D, how can I solve this with your solution?

Comment: @Vega df['D'] = df[['A','B','C']].gt({'A':1000,'B':600,'C':600}).any(1).astype(int)

Comment: @Vega YW:-) Happy coding ~

Answer (score 3):

Use:

```
df['D'] = (df['A'].gt(1000) | df['B'].gt(600) | df['C'].gt(600)).astype(int)
```

Or:

```
df['D'] = df.gt([1000,600,600]).any(1).astype(int)
```